# Intersects query with where clause and max time

Tags: where-clause, st-intersects

I am having an issue with this query. I am trying to select the buildings (gta_bldgs) that intersect with gps points (wherez) but when the speed is equal to zero and the most recent (Max devicetime). I have been struggling to make it work.

```
SELECT pkuid, name, type, a.geometry
FROM gta_bldgs AS a, (SELECT deviceid, devicetime, speed, geometry FROM wherez WHERE speed = 0) AS b
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geometry,b.geometry)
GROUP BY b.deviceid
HAVING b.Max(devicetime);
```